# Searching for specific element in Composite pattern

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, iterator, composite

Suppose I have a simple composite pattern structure:

- abstract class `User`
- leaf class `PersonalUser`
- composite class `GroupUser` with a `std::vector<User*> users` container as its member variable

and a method `bool GroupUser::findUser(User* u)` which returns `true` if the user `u` is found in the `users` container (which naturally consists of other `PersonalUser` or `GroupUser` objects)

Now, I'd like to define that function recursively of course, so I need to go through each `User` in `users` vector, and compare with `u`, but I won't know if the `User` is a `PersonalUser` or `GroupUser`, so my question is:

*Do I have to define a virtual function `char User::returnType()` which will tell me which type of `User` it is, or is there a better/smarter way to go down the tree and look for the `User`?*

p.s. there is of course a method like `bool areEqual(User*, User*)` by which we can compare users :)

Comment: Is a `GroupUser` really a `User`, or is it just a collection of `User`s?

Comment: Yeah, `GroupUser` is derived from `User`, and it has a collection (vector) of `User*`called `users` :P

Comment: I'm not asking whether it's derived or not (I figured that out), I'm saying a group of users is not logically a user...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - in many access management systems a group of users is actually a user as well.  It doesn't have to conflict, even if at face-value it doesn't seem too logical.

Comment: @MadKeithV seems like a code-smell to me.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Why couldn't a group of users that share a same trait be grouped into one User with that particular trait, and just be called GroupUser?

Comment: @Vidak they could. I'm just saying it's a bad design. Why does the Group have to be a user itself? What's wrong with just having a collection of users as member?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - that's actually just how the composite pattern works.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Well because there may be other groups of users inside the main group, e.g. the group consists of male users, and the male user group has one mathematician, one artist, and a group of engineers. By making the group of male users a User, we can now proceed making other specializations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the FindUser member function as a virtual to the abstract class User, and make it return true if the user being searched for is the current user (Personal or Group).

In GroupUser you can override FindUser and delegate any call to all the contained Users if the User being searched for isn't the current GroupUser.

Comment: but how will I delegate it to the contained Users if I'm writing the method in the class `User` which doesn't know anything about the collection of Users in the `GroupUser` class?

Comment: @Vidak - just override the FindUser in GroupUser, use the Composite pattern for its intended purpose :)

Answer (score 3):

As MadKeithV said, you declare the virtual function findUser(User*u) in the interface,
then:

```
bool
    User::findUser(User*u) {
        return u == this;
    }
```

and

```
GroupUser::findUser(User *u) {
    for (// loop on your users)
        if (currentUser.findUser(u))
            return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. `dynamic_cast<>()` to check if a `User*` is really a `GroupUser` or not, like this:

```
GroupUser* groupUser = dynamic_cast<GroupUser*>(userPointer);
```

If it returns a null pointer, then `userPointer` is not a `GroupUser`.